# recognize installed application

Tags: system, default-programs

I've a problem to make Ubuntu 13.10 to recognize my installed program.

I've installed Blender 3d from the site instead of USC and I've created the .desktop file. All run good but when I tried to open a *.blend* file the system tell me that there isn't appropriate program installed and also the dock bar I've installed can't make an icon of blender but only of the program that I've installed from USC.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your file type in the mime database.

[This tutorial](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor/) on freedesktop.org covers the details.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the directions to do that as part of your answer.

Comment: thanks but thats don't solve the problem. I need to make the system recognize blender as an installed application.